# How to make only the differences saved

Tags: go, orm, go-gorm

I have a function which is creating a record something like this:

```
func A(db *gorm.DB, b []C) error {
    d := []e{}
    for _, f := range b {
        d = append(d, g(f))
    }
    return db.Save(&d).Error
}
```

I want to be able to upload some data (which could potentially be the same), but I'd wish only the differences to be saved.

So if I upload the same data, I'd want that to happen without any problem, as there are no differences (or changes).

If I try to upload the same data, I get: `"error":"Error 1062: Duplicate entry '1' for key ...` but as mentioned earlier, I would not want this to happen. I'd wish this to get uploaded without any error.
I also did something like Upsert / On Conflict, but it didn't work (https://gorm.io/docs/create.html#Upsert-x2F-On-Conflict)

Thanks!

Comment: You're going to have to say WHAT didn't work if you expect anyone to be able to help you. Show the call, the code, dB schema and error message.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74247341/how-to-make-only-the-differences-saved-in-gorm